# Using firepad with node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firepad

How would I modify the text in a firepad editor on my webpage using Node?
What I'm trying to do is have the user upload a file, then read the contents of the file, and replace the firepad contents with the uploaded file's contents.

I see that there's a firepad npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/firepad, but it doesn't say how to use it with node.
I currently have it setup in my html and using a normal public js file in my node project.

So I was thinking that to update the text, I could either send a post request with the text, and my client side js would receive it and then update the firepad since it has access to the firepad variable there.

Or I could use the npm module, but I'm not sure if it's a full module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Firepad Headless docs](https://firepad.io/docs/#headless).  Here's an example:

```
var Firepad  = require('firepad')
var firepadRef = ... // create firebase database reference to your firepad data.
var headless = new Firepad.Headless(firepadRef)

headless.setText('Welcome to Firepad!', function(err, committed) {
  // *err*       will be set if there was a catastrophic failure
  // *committed* will be true on success, or false if there was a history
  //               conflict writing to the pad's history.
});
```

Comment: So actually, when I include just that first line `var Firepad  = require('firepad')`, I get an error `ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at c:\Users\user\git\eebooks\node_modules\firepad\dist\firepad.min.js:13:179`. I think it's because I'm running this on Node which is server-side and doesn't have access to the browser's window object.
So what should I do?

Comment: Ack!  Hrm.  Looks like something got broken.  Can you try using firepad 1.3.0 for now?  I've opened an issue to look into fixing 1.4.0: https://github.com/firebase/firepad/issues/251  Thanks for the report.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by replacing all instances of `window` with `global`

Comment: I'm using webpack and get this warning: `Critical dependencies:
2463:61-68 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/firepad/dist/firepad.js 2463:61-68`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround till the available npm version (1.4.0) gets the patch is to define window:

```
   global.window={};
   const Firepad = require('firepad');
```